# Shared Loss for Multitasking Model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am currently training a multitasking classification model.

When I training the model, I can see there are two loss metrics for my two classification output which are `species_loss` and also `diseases_loss` but what I am curious about is why there is another loss metric named `val_loss`? Is that a shared loss between `species_loss` and `diseases_loss`? Is it ok to directly  set my earlystopping monitor on that `val_loss` metrics?

```
Epoch 1/100
100/100 [==============================] - 134s 1s/step - loss: 0.5361 - species_loss: 0.1241 - diseases_loss: 0.4120 - species_accuracy: 0.9781 - diseases_accuracy: 0.9022 - val_loss: 2.9369 - val_species_loss: 0.1653 - val_diseases_loss: 2.7716 - val_species_accuracy: 0.9494 - val_diseases_accuracy: 0.5863
```

Comment: It is just the validation loss.

Comment: When you train your model you have validation data and val_loss is a loss for validation data and in your problem: `val_loss = val_species_loss + val_diseases_loss`

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks! However, may I still ask if it is appropriate to set the earlystopping condition based on that val_loss?

Comment: This (last one) is not a *programming* question but a methodology one - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info ; that said, I cannot see why not.